# Observers implementation with '\' before enums

Tags: ios, swift, observers

Recently I implemented a progress view to show the load process on web page. I read an example (https://gist.github.com/fxm90/50d6c73d07c4d9755981b9bb4c5ab931) and modified. But part of code is not clear for me, precisely

```
\.estimatedProgress
```

This is the relevant code.

```
var webView: WKWebView!
// Progress view reflecting the current loading progress of the web view.
let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
/// The observation object for the progress of the web view (we only receive notifications until it is deallocated).
private var estimatedProgressObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

private func setupEstimatedProgressObserver() {
    estimatedProgressObserver = webView.observe(\.estimatedProgress, options: [.new]) { [weak self] webView, _ in
        self?.progressView.progress = Float(webView.estimatedProgress)
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. Why and when you can use character '\' before an enums?
2. Is not necessary to make deinit or remove the observer using this way? Why?

Comment: That's for KeyPath https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/the-power-of-key-paths-in-swift etc ?

Answer (score 2):

The `\<Type>.<path>` syntax is a [Swift Key-Path expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html) (and not an enum) and is essentially a strongly typed reference to a path of some `Type`. When then type can be inferred, you can omit it and so the expression becomes `\.path` (in your example the full expression would be `\WKWebView.estimatedProgress`).

There are several examples in the above link that will help you understand this better.

For the second part, the observation will only last as long as `estimatedProgressObserver` is not deallocated (so, as long as something holds a strong reference to it).

Comment: Thanks for you answer.